# 1x1 Iframes blockage

Tags: iframe

I have a project where I need to use a 1x1 iframe. It's on a different domain, proper usage though.

My worries are that some browsers may block these iframes. I tested it on IE 6&8, FF 3.0, Chrome, Safari and they work.

I know 1x1 iframes can also be used for bad, so maybe there are cases where they are blocked.

Do you know addons/combinations that block 1x1 iframes? Is there a way to overwrite these things (it doesn't necessarily have to be 1x1, I just think it's ugly to add a banner or something).

NoScript disables all javascript so it doesn't count...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it 1x1, you could use style="display:none" on the iframe declaration. It is then equivalent to 0x0 frame. Even better.

-Oisin

Comment: probably visibility:hidden would be better, though it would leave empty space. I'm not sure display: none executes the content in all browsers.

1x1 is simple, I still don't know the impact though.

Comment: really? Would they really assume the iframe is not going be rendering non-visible content like javascript? Not sure I'm with you on this.

Comment: I'll have to test this particular case.

Comment: you could instead set `position:fixed;` and `opacity:0;`